# .netcore Azure functions startup class is not called

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions

My Azure function doesn't calls the startup class localy.
When running the project, my brekpoint doesn't hit the DependencyRegistrations.Register function.

Package Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions is correctly installed

```py
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            DependencyRegistrations.Register(builder.Services);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Why is the startup class not called?

Answer (score 8):

Two things I'm not seeing in your code snippet.

1- [assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]

2- Are you sure the nuget package was properly installed? (Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions)

The final startup code should look like the following:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyService>((s) => {
                return new MyService();
            });

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, MyLoggerProvider>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You were on to something. After doing a lot of things, I deleted obj and bin folders and was asked by compiler to do a NuGet restore. All good after that.

Answer (score 7):

Just in case you're running v4, Startup is not used.

Perform the dependency injection setup in Program.cs:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
        builder.AddTransient<ICompetitionService, CompetitionService>();
        builder.AddTransient<ICompetitionRepository, CompetitionRepository>();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Comment: I am on v4, Startup stopped being called after a move/rename project.

Comment: For me this was the fix... I've been frustrated for half a day about this. Thanks!!!

Comment: After battling to understand why startup wasn't being called, I tried this suggestion and it worked perfectly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue, i have to remove my project from my solution and recreate an new to have the statup to be called...

I suspect a version mistake somewhere